# Laravel. Не работает Auth:attempt()

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

В результате я получаю "fail". Все данные правильно поступают и правильно валидируются. База данных нормально выдаёт данные о users, так что не в ней проблема.
**$request->email** возвращает "alex@gmail.com",
**$request->password** возвращает "123321"

**UserController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function login(Request $request)
    {

        // Login form
        if ($request->isMethod("get")) {
            return view('login');
        }
        
        // Login validation
        if ($request->isMethod("post")) {

            $request->validate([
                'email' => ['required', 'max:255', 'email'],
                'password' => ['required', 'max:255'],
            ]);

            if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password])) {
                dd("success");
            } else {
                dd("fail");
            }

        }

    }

    public function logout()
    {
        Auth::logout();
        return redirect()->route('login');
    }
}
```

**User.php (модель)**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

// use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'email',
        'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for serialization.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast.
     *
     * @var array<string, string>
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
        'password' => 'hashed',
    ];
}
```

**Login.blade.php (форма)**

```
<form action="{{ route('login') }}" method="POST">

                    @csrf

                    <div class="input-group mb-3">
                        <input name="email" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" value="{{ old('email') }}">
                        <div class="input-group-append">
                            <div class="input-group-text">
                                <span class="fas fa-user"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group mb-3">
                        <input name="password" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
                        <div class="input-group-append">
                            <div class="input-group-text">
                                <span class="fas fa-lock"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Login</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

Comment: А как именно у вас хранится пароль в БД? Как хэш, или как есть?